# How to visualize diff between two graphs

Tags: d3.js, neo4j, visualization, data-visualization

I have two graphs. The first is the current graph, updated, and the second is the old one. The difference between these two graphs must be visualized with red color (node or link in red).

To be clear, I have two JSON files (I exported the DB into JSON files) and the difference between the two files should be visualized in red in the graph.

Could anyone help for to find the way to implement that?

Comment: which graph visualisation libraries are you using ?

Comment: As @ChristopheWillemsen asks, how are you viewing the graphs? You could do a `diff` on the JSON files and color code the textual difference in an editor, or you could generate a powerpoint in Java with `ApachePOI` and color the difference that way, or... . How and where do you want to present the difference?

Comment: As @MicTech said it depends a lot on your use case: are you interested in `diff` about properties or network structure? Probably you want to skip some properties (e.g. `id` ) while computing the `diff`.

Comment: What sort of graphs? Scatter?

Comment: I used Neo4j Database. I get a graph of users and there properties

Comment: and 2 difference between the 2 json files should be modeled in other color on the same graph

Answer (score 1):

Your question is more about the visualization than about the Neo4j.

Neo4j doesn't have any kind of this functionality out of the box.

It depends for what purpose you want to show difference between two graphs. You can use [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) for creating your own solution or try one of the existing visualization libraries for graphs - [Graph Visualization for Neo4j](http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-visualization/)

Could you please tell us more about your use case?

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.
I have 2 json files, the difference between them is new node created. this node I want to visualize it in red color

Comment: Could anyone help me to use jsondiffpatch to get the difference between 2 json files and make this difference in different color on the graph

Comment: @Aminael What kind of technology do you use for a visualization?

Comment: I use **alchemy** using Neo4j and PHP